# Find the area of a surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Find the area of the part of the sphere $S = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1 \} $ cut by the $z \geq 59· \sqrt{x^2+y^2} $ cone.

I have tried to find the intersection curve but then I don't know what else to do. Should I change to spherical coordinates?

Any hint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Actually, you are asked to evaluate the given integral $$\iint_{S} dS; \text {where, S is the surface of the given sphere cut by the given cone. }$$
Now, take the projection of the intersection curve on $xy$-plane, we get circle $x^2+y^2=\frac{1}{1+59^2}$ and we use the surface of the sphere to find $dS=\sqrt{1+z_x^{2}+z_y^{2}}dxdy=\frac{1}{|z|}dxdy=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}dxdy$. We use polar coordinate system to reduce the calculations, the integral becomes:
$$\text{Surface area}= \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+59^2}}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-r^2}} r dr d{\theta}.$$

Comment: What do $z_x$ and $z_y$ mean?

Comment: Sorry,  I had to define them. $z_x=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $z_y=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$. Is it clear now?

Comment: So in this case, that $z = \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$? The expression where you do those partial derivatives?

Comment: yes, as we have to find the surface area of the sphere with some restrictions. BTW you can find partial derivatives easily by taking $z^2=1-x^2-y^2$, Don't you? (Hint: $z=f(x,y)$)

Comment: Thank you, I understand that. But I don't know why $dS= \sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}dxdy$.

Comment: This may help you in understanding the basic ideas. http://home.iitk.ac.in/~psraj/mth101/lecture_notes/lecture35.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much @Learning.

Answer (score 2):

In cylindrical coordinates, the two given surfaces are $r^2+z^2=1$ and $z=59r$. They intersect at the radius

$$r=\frac1{\sqrt{1+59^2}} $$

Given that the radius is fairly small, the spherical cutout is of a tiny circle and its area can then be approximated as

$$\pi r^2 \approx \frac{\pi}{59^2}$$

Comment: +1 , elegant answer!